# How to run a function with no parameters defined?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am trying to create a code that does not require parameters to determine if one is qualified for a loan, but the function takes years and annual wage into account to determine if qualified. How can I get the function to take inputs without parameters?

edit: I cannot give it parameters becausse that is what was asked of me. To create this function without parameters.

```
def loan():
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    To qualify for a loan, the annual salary must be 30000 or more and  
    employee must have worked for a minimum of 5 years
    Use: qualified = loan()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        qualified - True if employee qualifies for a loan,
            False otherwise (boolean)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    MIN_SALARY =30000
    MIN_YEARS = 5
    if years < 5:
        qualified = False 
    elif years >= MIN_YEARS:
        if salary >= MIN_SALARY:
            qualified = True 
        else: 
            qualified = False 
    else:
        qualified = False 
    return qualified

#--------------Main Program-----------------#

years = int(input('Years employed: '))
salary = float(input('Annual salary: '))
qualified = loan(years = years, salary = salary)
print()
print('Qualified for a loan: {}'.format(qualified))
```

Comment: Why not just give `loan` parameters? If it takes arguments, it needs parameters.

Comment: If you use a class you can use self.money or self.min_salary. Then you can have a class method that only takes in one "parameter," self

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't just add those parameters, but this could possibly help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs

Comment: There is not a reproducible problem here. "How do I do things in the poorly-designed way that my instructor wants me to do them?" is not on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. What I did was add the inputs into the code itself.

```
def loan():
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    To qualify for a loan, the annual salary must be 30000 or more and  
    employee must have worked for a minimum of 5 years
    Use: qualified = loan()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        qualified - True if employee qualifies for a loan,
            False otherwise (boolean)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    years =(int(input('Years employed: ')))
    salary = (float(input('Annual salary: ')))
    #rest of the function
```

Comment: I'm sure that meets the requirements of the exercise, but it is very poor design. Separation of input from calculation is a very basic modularization technique.

Comment: Yes, ideally, functions should just take and return data. Functions that handle their own acquisition of data are harder to test and reuse.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use [keyword args](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769475/1079354) for this...

```
def loan(**kwargs):
    ...
```

...but the more sensible and practical thing would be to **specify the parameters you expect to be passed into the function**.

```
def loan(years, salary):
    ...
```

Methods aren't magical and they have their own scope.  If you don't add variables to that scope, then the only way you'd get information is [from global scope](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#the-global-statement), which is expressly discouraged and also wholly unnecessary in this case.